# Torsionfree and associated primes

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, modules, maximal-and-prime-ideals

I'm trying to prove the following:

> If $R$ is a Noetherian ring, $M$ a finitely generated module, then $M$ is torsionfree iff the associated primes of $M$ are contained in the associated primes of $R$.

I tried to prove the forward direction, but got confused. My attempt: Let $P$ be an associated prime of $M$. Then there is a non-zero element $x\in M$ such that $P=ann(x)$. Let $p_1,...,p_n$ be generators of $P$. For any $i$, since $p_ix=0$ and $M$ is torsionfree, then $p_i$ must be a zero-divisor in $R$, i.e., there must be $0\neq r_i\in R$ such that $p_ir_i=0$. I claim that $p=ann(r_1\cdots r_n)$. I dont know if this will be the case, but I also dont know if $r_1\cdots r_n=0$ in which case, the my idea wont be helpful. Any ideas are welcomed!

Comment: If $a\in R$ is a non-zerodivisor, and $x\in M$ such that $ax=0$, then every prime minimal over the annihilator of $x$ is an associated prime of $M$, hence an associated prime of $R$. But it contains a non-zerodivisor in $R$, a contradiction.

Comment: @user26857 He asked for the other direction, didn't he?

Comment: @MooS Don't know. Did he? Anyway, that direction is wrong, so the OP's try is in vain. I suggest him to look for a counterexample. (Of course, when $R$ has no embedded primes this holds, too. This shows that a ring of the form $K[X,Y,Z]/(X^2,XY,XZ)$ can be a good candidate.)

Comment: You are of couse right. Just take a prime ideal $P$, which contains only zero-divisors but is not associated. Then $M=R/P$ is torsionfree and $P=\operatorname {ann}(1)$ is an associated prime of $M$. In your ring one can take $(X,Y)$.

Comment: Maybe the OP missed a hypothesis like reduced.

Comment: There seems to be an error on the wikipedia page on torsion free modules, because it seems to state that this equivalence is correct. Though it used the correct definition of torsion free.

Comment: Could I ask why every prime minimal over the annihilator of $x$ is an associated prime of $M?$

Comment: I think it's simple enough to say that there exists an associated prime of $M$ that contains the annihilator of $x$: the contrapositive holds by the Prime Avoidance Lemma.

Comment: @MooS, is it correct to say that the equivalence holds over a Cohen-Macaulay ring? For instance, I believe that your counterexample is impossible there.