# Restricting a module to the irreducible components of an affine curve is injective

Tags: algebraic-geometry, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, modules

The question is originally coming from a non-affine case, but I will only consider the affine one here.

Let $R$ be a ring which is reduced and has only a finite number of minimal prime ideals $P_1,\ldots,P_r$. Let $M$ be a finitely generated and torsion-free $R$-module (where the latter means that no regular element in $R$ can annihilate a non-zero element of $M$). There is a canonical map

$$R \to \prod_{i=1}^r R/P_i$$
which is injective since its kernel is given by $\bigcap_{i=1}^r P_i = \operatorname{Rad}(R) = 0$.

> If we tensor this morphism with $M$, is it still injective? That is, is the morphism
>   $$\varphi:M \to \prod_{i=1}^r M/P_iM$$
>   injective?

It certainly is (by definition) if $M$ is flat.

- But does the torsion-freeness suffice?
- If not, can you give a counter example?
- What are far less restrictive assumption on $M$ such that $\varphi$ is injective?

Of course, the reduceness of $R$ would help here again if $\bigcap_{i=1}^r P_iM \stackrel{??}{=} (\bigcap_{i=1}^r P_i)M = 0$. But I don't see why this should be true.

---

**Edit:** I forgot to mention that I work with curves and thus we also have $\dim R = 1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\newcommand{\ass}{\operatorname{Ass}} \newcommand{\p}{\mathfrak{p}} \newcommand{tm}{\subseteq}$

> **Proposition:** Let $R$ be a reduced ring and let $M$ be a torsion-free $R$-module. Then the map $M \to \prod_{P \in \ass(R)} M/PM$ is injective.

**Proof:** By [Tag 0AVL](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0AVL) it suffices to show that the induced local homomorphism for all associated primes of $M$ is injective. The torsion-free assumption on $M$ provides $\ass(M) \tm \ass(R)$ (see [Torsionfree and associated primes](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2307847/torsionfree-and-associated-primes)) and thus it suffices to show the injectivity at minimal primes of $R$. Let $\p \in \ass(R)$ be a minimal prime of $R$. Then the localized homomorphism is $M_{\p} \to \prod_{P \in \ass(R)} (M/PM)_\p$. But for every minimal $\p \neq P$ we have $(M/PM)_\p = 0$ and thus the morphism is simply given by $M_\p \to (M/\p M)_\p \cong M_\p$ where the last isomorphism holds for minimal primes.

*Remark:* As the proof shows, we see that the above injection factors through $\prod_{P \in \ass(M)} M/PM$.

Answer (score 0):

$M\to S^{-1}M$ is injective, where $S$ is the set of regular elements. But $S^{-1}R$ is just a product of fields and the rest should be clear.

Comment: I am not sure what I miss, but what you're saying is that the morphism $M \to \prod_i M_{P_i}$ is injective. So far I can follow, but where is the connection to the morphism $M \to \prod_i M/P_iM$?

Comment: $M_{P_i}=(M/P_iM)_{P_i}$.

Comment: Okay, I think I got it. From https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0AVL we know that we only need to check the injectivity at the associated primes of $M$ and those are a subset of the minimal primes of $R$ by the torsion-free assumption on $M$. Is this correct?